# Android BufferedReader instance cannot be resolved at finally trying to close it

Tags: java, android

I have omitted irrelevant parts of the code:

```
[...]
    try {
        URL url = new URL(updateUrl);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
[...]
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
[...]
```

The problem is that on the finally "input.close()" Eclipse says that "input cannot be resolved".

I think it may be an scope problem, but I have seen code from other guys and it has usually this same form, so I do not know why it is not working here.

Any hints?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a scope error.
Your `input` is declared inside the `try` block, so it can't be seen inside the `finally` block. Declare it outside, so that it is visible to both, and you should be fine:

```
[...]
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(updateUrl);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
[...]
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (input != null)
        {
            try {
              input.close();
            }
            catch (IOException exc)
            {
              exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sometimes after too much coding you are so offuscated that does not see such obvius things. I will select your answer as soon as stackoverflow let me doing it (it says that I must wait seven minutes)

Comment: Make sure that in your `finally` block you check whether `input` is `null` before trying to close it. If your URL is malformed, `input` will never be assigned to, but you'll still try to call close on it.

Comment: @Hbcdev Good point, updated the code. And Fran: you're welcome.

Comment: Erm... now I do not know who was the first that gives the right answer. I think it was you, because the first time I see these answers your one was first...

Answer (score 1):

declare `BufferedReader`  **input** instance  globally or outside first try/catch block as:

```
[...]
BufferedReader input;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(updateUrl);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
[...]
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it is a scope problem.  Java uses block scope, which means local variables declared in one scope are invisible in any scope that is not contained within it.  `try` blocks and `finally` blocks are not exceptions to this rule.

```
BufferedReader input;
try {
    URL url = new URL(updateUrl);
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log or ignore this
        }
    }
}
```